# Error consola navegador: Uncaught TypeError: peliculas.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, funciones, map

Estaba haciendo un proyecto de una aplicación web en la cual escribes el título de una película y te salen los resultados.

El problema es el siguiente, al escribir cualquier película y hacer click en buscar, desaparece todo y cuando abro la consola del navegador me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: Error en consola]

Así se ve la página si no busco nada:
[image: Página si no se hace búsqueda]

Aquí les comparto el código:

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const BuscadorPeliculas = () => {
  const urlBase = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie"
  const API_KEY = "a7e7d73b172d153cabdced8c2089e64c"
  const [busqueda, setBusqueda] = useState("")
  const [peliculas, setPeliculas] = useState([])

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setBusqueda(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetchPeliculas()
  }

  const fetchPeliculas = async () => {
    try{
      const response = await fetch(`${urlBase}?query=${busqueda}&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
      const data = await response.json()
      setPeliculas(data)
    } catch(error) {
      console.error("Ha ocurrido un error: ", error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1 className="title">Buscador Peliculas</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Escribi una pelicula"
          value={busqueda}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        <button type="submit" className="search-button">Buscar</button>
      </form>
      <div className="movie-list">
        {peliculas.map( (pelicula) => {
          <div key={pelicula.id} className="movie-card">
            <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${pelicula.poster_path}`} alt={pelicula.title} />
            <h2>{pelicula.title}</h2>
            <p>{pelicula.overview}</p>
          </div>
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Agradecería su ayuda, desde ya gracias.

Comment: Estás seguro que `data` es un Array? Has depurado ese valor? Porque lo asignas directamente a `peliculas` (`setPeliculas(data)` ) y si no es un Array, entonces es claro que `peliculas.map` no estaría definido

Answer (score -1):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como digo en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/611727/error-consola-navegador-uncaught-typeerror-peliculas-map-is-not-a-function#comment1078194_611727), no estás depurando correctamente la respuesta recibida desde el backend.

Resulta que usando la siguiente petición:

> `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=a7e7d73b172d153cabdced8c2089e64c&query=titanic`

La respuesta que se recibe tiene el siguiente formato:

```json
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/xnHVX37XZEp33hhCbYlQFq7ux1J.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        10749
      ],
      "id": 597,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Titanic",
      "overview": "101-year-old Rose DeWitt Bukater tells the story of her life aboard the Titanic, 84 years later. A young Rose boards the ship with her mother and fiancé. Meanwhile, Jack Dawson and Fabrizio De Rossi win third-class tickets aboard the ship. Rose tells the whole story from Titanic's departure through to its death—on its first and last voyage—on April 15, 1912.",
      "popularity": 122.852,
      "poster_path": "/9xjZS2rlVxm8SFx8kPC3aIGCOYQ.jpg",
      "release_date": "1997-11-18",
      "title": "Titanic",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.9,
      "vote_count": 24115
    },
    { ... }
  ],
  "total_pages": 10,
  "total_results": 191
}
```

Claramente cuando haces:

```js
  // ...
  const data = await response.json()
  setPeliculas(data)
```

El valor de `data`no es un Array, sino que es un objeto que tiene entre sus propiedades, una llamada `results` que es efectivamente la lista de películas correspondiente a la búsqueda.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero es arreglar tu función de búsqueda, para realmente obtener los datos que esperas mostrar en tu página.

Una forma podría ser la siguiente:

```js
const fetchPeliculas = async () => {
  try{
    const response = await fetch(`${urlBase}?query=${busqueda}&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
    const { results } = await response.json()
    // sólo seteamos el valor de peliculas si existe results y este es un Array y tiene datos
    if (Array.isArray(results) && results.length) {
      setPeliculas(results)
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.error("Ha ocurrido un error: ", error)
  }
}
```

De esta forma el valor de `peliculas` siempre será con garantía un Array.

Por otro lado, una buena práctica en React es pintar o renderizar un elemento sólo si es necesario, independientemente del resultado anterior que nos garantiza que `peliculas`es efectivamente un Array.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div className="movie-list">
  {Array.isArray(peliculas) && peliculas.map( (pelicula) => {
    <div key={pelicula.id} className="movie-card">
      <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${pelicula.poster_path}`} alt={pelicula.title} />
      <h2>{pelicula.title}</h2>
      <p>{pelicula.overview}</p>
    </div>
  })}
</div>
```

De esta forma si llegases a tener un valor diferente a un Array almacenado en `peliculas` la primera condición `Array.isArray(peliculas)` evaluaría a `false` y nunca se llamaría a `peliculas.map`, lo cual evitaría el error y simplemente no se renderizaría nada.